# Input within a time limit in Standard C

Tags: c

I'm currently doing my assignment and it's compulsory to use C-Free 5.0. Just need your help to solve this piece of puzzle. I want to implement a time limit for the user to input an answer before it expires. I've tried this code but it got block at scanf() function. Is there any other method like an unblocking input or something. I've tried to implement '`#include <sys/select.h>`' but this program doesn't have that library.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char st[10];
    printf ("Please enter a line of text : ");
    time_t end = time(0) + 5; //5 seconds time limit.
    while(time(0) < end)
    {
        scanf("%s", &st);
        if(st != NULL)
        {
            printf ("Thank you, you entered >%s<\n", st);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    main();
}
```

Comment: Judging from [Program Arts](http://www.programarts.com/cfree_en/) web site, C-Free 5.0 is a Windows-based IDE.  It has support for Cygwin as the compiler, amongst others...which compiler, as opposed to IDE, are you using?

Comment: Do you have `alarm()` available to you, and does `<signal.h>` define SIGALRM?

Comment: Then take a look here: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/105314-time-limit-user-input.html The other option would be to use threads I guess.

Comment: I've tried the code but sadly I don't have certain libraries like `#include <sys/ipc.h>` and `#include <sys/shm.h>`...and I have these errors as well...SIGCHLD and SIGALRM not declared..

Comment: In your question's subject you say "Standard C". The answer to the question is "no." All standard I/O routines are blocking and there's no provision for asynchronous I/O. alarm(), select(), ipc.h, etc, are not "Standard C".

Comment: shoots...so meaning I can't implement this feature...

Comment: Yeap I do have <fcntl.h>

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example program that shows how you can use `O_NONBLOCK` flag on a `stdin` file descriptor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define INPUT_LEN 10

int main()
{
    printf ("Please enter a line of text : ");
    fflush(stdout);
    time_t end = time(0) + 5; //5 seconds time limit.

    int flags = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    char answer[INPUT_LEN];
    int pos = 0;
    while(time(0) < end)
    {
        int c = getchar();

        /* 10 is new line */
        if (c != EOF && c != 10 && pos < INPUT_LEN - 1)
            answer[pos++] = c;

        /* if new line entered we are ready */
        if (c == 10)
            break;
    }

    answer[pos] = '\0';

    if(pos > 0)
        printf("%s\n", answer);
    else
        puts("\nSorry, I got tired waiting for your input. Good bye!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `fcntl.h` try setting stdin to non-blocking. It's not pretty (active waiting), but if you do not have `select` then this is the easyest way to go:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    // get stdin flags
    int flags = fcntl(0, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags == -1) {
        // fcntl unsupported
        perror("fcntl");
        return -1;
    }

    // set stdin to non-blocking
    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    if(fcntl(0, F_SETFL, flags) == -1) {
        // fcntl unsupported
        perror("fcntl");
        return -1;
    }

    char st[1024] = {0}; // initialize the first character in the buffer, this is generally good practice
    printf ("Please enter a line of text : ");
    time_t end = time(0) + 5; //5 seconds time limit.

    // while
    while(time(0) < end  // not timed out
        && scanf("%s", st) < 1 // not read a word
        && errno == EAGAIN); // no error, but would block

    if (st[0]) // if the buffer contains something
        printf ("Thank you, you entered >%s<\n", st);

    return 0;
}
```

A remark to your code: `if (st != NULL)` will always be satisfied since `st` is a stack pointer.

Comment: No, I did not, but it wasn't intended to be a full program anyways. Have put in a full program now and this one is tested and works on OS X, gcc 4.2